# How to get the values of multiple select box and display the result in textbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a dropdown with list of items,each item holding each price. Once selecting the items,its total price to be populated in the textbox. This is my dropdown-

```
   <select name="treatment[]" class="col-sm-12 country" id="" multiple="multiple">    
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <?php foreach($treatment as $treatments) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $treatments->treatment_name ?>"><?php echo $treatments->treatment_name ?></option>
       <?php }?>                      
   </select>
```

I was trying to do using ajax,but i am lost.anyone can help me out?thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that price stored inside same table with item in database?

Comment: yes,i was thinking like if using ajax- by linking with another function can fetch the price of the item.

Comment: Then you should go to `DrunkWolf` answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> each item holding each price

If the `price` was stored together with `item` in same table, you just need to add `data attributes` into `option` for additional data. If not better `Joined it` in your codeigniter controller or model to link together all the price with items. Here is example i can show to you :

Supposed you have **HTML** structure like this :

```
<select name="treatment[]" class="col-sm-12 country" id="" multiple="multiple">
 // this line of code loop by php
 // see data-price attribute store Price inside
 // later we can referencing this attribute
 <option value="fish" data-price="200">Fish</option>
 <option value="chicken" data-price="500">Chicken</option>
</select>
// place to display total
<input type="text" id="total" />
```

And here **jQuery** code for sum up all selected items :

```
$('.country').click(function () {
  var price = 0;
   $('option:selected', $(this)).each(function () {
     //console.log($(this).data('price'));
     // sum price for selected items
     price += $(this).data('price');
  });
  $('#total').val(price);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/ykre8oza/1/)**

**UPDATED**

If you are using inline javascript like `onchange`, then you need to send it reference into function that you want to call like so :

In HTML part change into this : `onchange="update_price(this)"`, and JS like follow :

```
function update_price(e) {
                   // ^ add this
 //$('#treatment').on('change',function () { comment this

  var price = 0;                          
  $('option:selected', $(e)).each(function() {
                      // ^ add this
    console.log($(this).data('pricetag'));
    // sum price for selected items
    price += $(this).data('pricetag');

  });
  $('#total').val(price);
//}); comment this
}
```

Comment: -sir,but what if the class=country is used bt many other fields,will that be a problem?

Comment: Supposed to be not because we are using `$('option:selected', $(this))` line of code that only trigger for clicked element for that option.

Comment: Your answer seems much simple to work out,but my bad the total is not being displayed,I cannot see the result in console too.

Comment: Carefully checked the element `id` or `class`. Better post your relevant HTML structured. Did you try implemented my example ?

Comment: There is something wrong html structure. Share your code and implementation you done

Comment: i have added small modifications on the script, but if adding only one items the price is not displayed,if selecting more than one items the prices are added and displayed.

Comment: Your answer got worked,am pretty new user in stackoverflow,so just learning out everything.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as i get it, your treatments have a price, and you want to add that to a textbox on selecting. You have 2 options to do so really

1) You add the price information to the option

```
<option 
    value="<?= $treatment->name ?>" 
    data-pricetag="<?= $treatment->priceinfo ?>"
>
..
</option>
```

And then with jquery you populate some textfield on select change

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    var text = $( "select option:selected" ).data('pricetag');
    $('#textfield').text(text);
}
```

2) you request price information from the server on select

```
 <option 
        value="<?= $treatment->id ?>" 
 >
    ..
 </option>
```

and then with jquery ask for the information

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
   var id = $(this).val();
   $.post('pricedata.php',{id:id},function(data){
       $('#textfield').text(data);
   });
}
```

Where pricedata.php uses $_POST['id'] to query for the correct pricing information, and return it in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine javascript to do so. PHP generates an array in javascript and the < option> value must be such as product ID, with javascript runs the selected items and add them using the array. Then the server sends the id of the products and do the same if you want to make a shopping cart.

If you want to Ajax , you have to do the same as in the previous paragraph , but send items to a url , and that returns the sum , and then put the result of Ajax in the item you want. The first option may be easier for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

**Norlihazmey Ghazali**- Below is my modified script code,the problem i noticed is even if we select an item the script is not working, i just tried by giving an alert inside and it's not displayed.

```js
$('select #treatment option').click(function () {
   alert('Hello');
  var price = 0;
  
   $('select #treatment option:selected', $(this)).each(function () {
     console.log($(this).data('price'));
     // sum price for selected items
     price += $(this).data('price');
  alert(price);
  });
  $('#total').val(price);
});
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-9">
                     <select name="treatment[]" class="col-sm-12 country" id="treatment" multiple="multiple">
                   
                     <option value="">--Select--</option>
                        
                        <?php foreach($treatment as $treatments) { ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $treatments->treatment_id ?>" data-price="<?= $treatments->treatment_price?>"><?php echo $treatments->treatment_name ?></option>
                       <?php }?>
                      
       
                     </select>
                 </div>
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-9">
     
 <input type="text" name="price" id="total" class="form-control" placeholder=""/>
     
</div>
```

Comment: You can't post in answer part, please update your question with this things. There are a few changes need to be done on your code.